# Why should I gitignore the .elastbeanstalk folder?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk Python Application.

So I already made my build script where I do generate a deploy.zip file that I do deploy into EB. It does work just as it suppose to.

So after building my script for building an artifact (my deploy.zip) that is compatible with EB, I began to work on configuring EB cli for using `eb deploy` in my gitlab-ci, so it will deploy to EB homologation server when there be a commit on development branch and into EB production when get into master. ( right now I'm just working on homologation server).

So I did read the documentation and notice that eb would build the artifactory by itself. But as I already had my own build script, this Deploying an [Artifact Instead of the Project Folder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html) so I made a `.elasticbeanstalk` folder and a `config.yml` in it with the follow configuration.

```
deploy:
     artifact: deploy.zip
```

So I did a `eb init`, did set everything (region, id, key and selected my existing project.

When I did `eb deploy` it worked just as it suppose to. So I did suspect that `eb` was making de artifactory by itself, so I checked the config file and notice that `eb` had add a bunch of other config into the file, my deploy config was there, so for another test I did deleted my `deploy.zip` so when I did a `eb deploy` it failed just as it suppose to.

Until this point everything was running just as I was planning to, so I did a `git status` for checking before adding the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder into git. For my surprise the folder was not been listed and the `.gitignore` file was changed. When checking the `.gitignore` it had the `.elasticbeanstalk` in it.

So it got me alert about if I should add this folder into the git, as de default behavior of `eb` is to add it into ignore.

I was planning to commit the eb configurations and set the keys using environment variables as is says in [Configuration Settings and Precedence](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html) session.

I've tried to run `eb deploy` without the configurations just passing env vars before the command, something like `AWSAccessKeyId=<access_key> AWSSecretKey=<secret_key>  eb deploy`, but it says that I should run `eb init` before it.

So shouldn't I track my `eb` configuration in my git repo? If not, how should I procede for a CI deploy with EB ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.elasticbeanstalk` is a place where eb cli stores it's configuration. As you wrote - one file `config.yml` is there, so you can create it by yourself. When you call `eb init` your version is overwritten, by the command.

If you have only one environment, or security is not an issue - then having that configuration in your repository is good idea. You are exposing some details like ssh key name, so for security reasons not all should see it. By all I men public repo. Perhaps that is why they put it to `.gitignore`.

Note that usually you have `test`, `pre-prod`, `prod`, environments - so configuration is needed anyway. Next step is a separate configuration repository for all that devopsish stuff, and there you can have directory, or branch per environment.

I agree with you that it looks strange - `.ebextensions` are not secured that way...

If I miss something - post question, I'll append clarification to this answer.